# How to filter table name not a database name in Navigator. It seems there's no option for filtering

Tags: dbeaver

[image]

As you see, it's `Database name to filter`. There's just few databases. So no need to filter 'Database name`. I need to change it to 'Table name to filter'. But it seems there's no option for it.

Weird thing is, it was a 'Database name to filter' at the time of first installation. I don't know when and how it changed.

Comment: which version of Dbeaver are you on? I'm on 6.0.2 and mine does filter tables by default. Perhaps it was changed in a recent version.

Comment: @Anepicpastry It's 5.2.201903XXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-installed it and it's done :(